# lambda-style function in php

Tags: php, lambda

See the code below.

```
 $newfunc = create_function('$a,$b', 'return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);');
 echo "New anonymous function: $newfunc\n";
 echo $newfunc(2, M_E) . "\n";

 // outputs
 // New anonymous function: lambda_1
 // ln(2) + ln(2.718281828459) = 1.6931471805599
```

Can any one tell how come it output lambda_1 when print $newfunc? 
and different output on second time.

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/sWHyUMSK)

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong...just could not understood how it worked. Hope you can help me.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? What aspect of the function is your question about?

Comment: @Pekka: My question is, why it returned lambda_1 for echo "New anonymous function: $newfunc\n"; And adding more to it, when i refresh that page it increment that number by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just that anonymous functions are internally named lambda_1, lambda_2, etc. 
So you the first echo statement gives "New anonymous function: lambda_1"

The function itself is returning a string, hence the second echo statement (`echo $newfunc(2, M_E) . "\n";`
) gives `ln(2) + ln(2.718281828459) = 1.6931471805599`